# Pass a complete string url in http get params

Tags: php, url, get

i try 
http://localhost/example?url=http://www.examenple.com/nice=url-get.aspx?n=value1&p=value2&params3=value3

but when i get a url params with

```
$url = $_GET["url"];
echo $url;
```

echo value
http://www.examenple.com/nice=url-get.aspx?n=value1

how to get a complete url param

Comment: You'll need to url encode it first.

Comment: Be careful with this method your opening yourself up to a XSS attack, make sure you check its a url before storing/echoing it out. my2cent ;p

Answer (score 0):

When the server parses the request URL to detect the GET parameters, it splits the URL near every & characters:

```
url=http://www.examenple.com/nice=url-get.aspx?n=value1 
&
p=value2
&
params3=value3
```

Hence the `$_GET` will have 3 members, url, p, and params3.

To avoid this, you need to replace every & characters with something else. This is called URL encoding. In PHP, there's a function for this: [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
$page = "http://www.examenple.com/nice=url-get.aspx?n=value1&p=value2&params3=value3";
echo "http://localhost/example?url=" . urlencode($page);
```

---

In case you can't access the source, and the input URL, but you can be sure there is only one, the url parameter which will be passed to your page, you can try this:

```
$url = $_GET["url"];
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == "url") continue;
    $url .= "&" . $key . "=" $value;
}
```

Comment: Judging by the tags, I don't think the url parameter is being generated in PHP.

Comment: @FirstOne Then it should. :)

Comment: I meant it should be generated somewhere, and so you can encode it. You're right in that it's totally unclear how he gets the input URL. He should edit the question if what I assumed is not the case.